# Code being saved to formatted workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template that user will open up, select the text file and VBA does all the magic.  At the end of the code I have the SaveAs dialog box come up, user type in name and saves to appropriate location. I have this code sitting in a module of the main temmplate.  The problem I have is the formatted file has the module in it where the code sits.  I don't want that.  I know I've figured this out before but today is not that day.  Relevant code pasted below.  I've tried changing the file formats, moving code to a worksheet.  What am I missing/forgetting?

```
    Filename = "WhateverName_"
    SaveThiisFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Filename, _
                                       fileFilter:="Excel Files   (*.xls), *.xls", _
                                       FilterIndex:=1, Title:="Save As")
    If ThisFile = False Then Exit Sub
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveThisFile
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
```

Comment: Can you save it as .xlsx file?  This would get rid of the vba code.  Only works if you're not still using Excel 03 (11 years old!)

Comment: I've tried that and I get error 'This extension can not be sued with selected file type, change the fle extensino in the file name box or select a different file type...'  But I'm expressing the file filter.

Comment: There is an option in the SaveAs method for specifying the file type - choose 51.

Comment: I only changed this `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveThisFile, FileFormat:=51` and code still appears.

Comment: Did you close and open the workbook with a new instance of Excel?  A .xlsx file can't store vba code.  Did it save as .xlsx?

Comment: It doesn't close and open a new workbook.  I currently have it set to do the saveas and close the workbook with code and I'm not able to saveas xlsx, error msg.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58023/discussion-between-mrbungle-and-dave-gugg).